# Default install of vue-cli-plugin-cordova will not run on ios simulator

Tags: cordova, vue.js

The steps outlined include

```
vue create my-app
vue add cordova
npm run cordova-prepare
npm run cordova-serve-browser
```

This works OK

```
npm run cordova-serve-ios
```

Many sites recommend variations changing this

```
new Vue({
    el:'#app',

    mounted:{
       alert("Vue is running");
    }
})
```

To this

```
const app = new Vue({
    el:'#app',

    methods:{
        init:function() {
            alert("Vue is running");
        }
    }
})

document.addEventListener('deviceready', app.init);
```

My site still come up blank on IOS simulator. FYI: Android does not have this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is important to get

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', app.init);
```

working right, this issue turned out to be that the ios simulator wanted to use a secure connection the the generated js files. It never even loaded in anything related to VueJS.

I had to change `vue.config.js` from

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '',
  pluginOptions: {
    cordovaPath: 'src-cordova'
  }
}
```

To

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '',
  pluginOptions: {
    cordovaPath: 'src-cordova'
  },
  devServer: {
    https: false
  }
}
```

Credit needs to go to: https://github.com/m0dch3n/vue-cli-plugin-cordova/issues/85

Answer (score 0):

Step 2 from [This article](https://medium.com/@dlodeprojuicer/using-cordova-in-an-ionic-vue-app-the-almost-complete-guide-d6423c248257) shows how to add cordova using vue cli

> Integrate Cordova into Vue Cli, you can install the cli integration plugin separately with npm install vue-cli-plugin-cordova but by adding Cordova to Vue, vue-cli-plugin-cordova is installed in the process.

Comment: I had not trouble getting that part to work. I could even get the site to generate a browser site.