# Unable to add vue-cli-plugin-cordova

Tags: vue.js, cordova, vue-cli

**system info:**

- @vue/cli-service: 4.5.9,
- vue: 2.6.12,

**issue reproduce steps:**
execute cmd: $ vue add cordova

**result:**

Installing vue-cli-plugin-cordova...

yarn add v1.22.5

[1/4] Resolving packages...

[2/4] Fetching packages...

info fsevents@2.1.3: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.

info "fsevents@2.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.

info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.

info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.

[3/4] Linking dependencies...

[4/4] Building fresh packages...

success Saved 1 new dependency.

info Direct dependencies
└─ vue-cli-plugin-cordova@2.4.1

info All dependencies
└─ vue-cli-plugin-cordova@2.4.1

$ npm run build

> NuStrength@0.1.0 build D:\Repos\NUS\NUS FE

> vue-cli-service build

ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'cordovaPath' of undefined

TypeError: Cannot read property 'cordovaPath' of undefined

```
at module.exports (D:\Repos\NUS\NUS FE\node_modules\vue-cli-plugin-cordova\index.js:29:45)

at D:\Repos\NUS\NUS FE\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:78:7

at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

at Service.init (D:\Repos\NUS\NUS FE\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:76:18)

at Service.run (D:\Repos\NUS\NUS FE\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\Service.js:215:10)

at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Repos\NUS\NUS FE\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\bin\vue-cli-service.js:36:9)

at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)

at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)

at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)

at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! errno 1

npm ERR! NuStrength@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Failed at the NuStrength@0.1.0 build script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\navu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-12-11T08_19_10_099Z-debug.log

[image]

*Has anyone got an issue like this or know the resolved solution?*
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem here. I solved by adding the following on the vue.config.js file:

```
pluginOptions: {
  cordovaPath: 'src-cordova'
}
```

Example file with addition:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '',
  pluginOptions: {
    cordovaPath: 'src-cordova'
  }
}
```

I got this by reading this topic: [Default install of vue-cli-plugin-cordova will not run on ios simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61537600/default-install-of-vue-cli-plugin-cordova-will-not-run-on-ios-simulator)